# Extract hour information from a date string

Tags: php, string, datetime

Is it possible extract hour value from a date string like below

```
20151211091805 +0000
```

**expected output-**

`09:18:05` (this should also be string)

Comment: This is a mysql timestamp value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$t = "20151211091805";
echo date('H:i:s',strtotime($t));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

```
echo date("H:i:s", strtotime("20151211091805"));
```

Another way using [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class.

```
$dateTime = new DateTime("20151211091805");                             
echo $dateTime->format('H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<?php
 $timestamp = 20151211091805;
 $date = new DateTime("$ts");
 echo date_format($date, 'H:i:s');
?>
```